# How to use UITableView to change the content of UITextView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

i need your support to use Static UITable view with static with UITextView
Where i need to change the content of TextView when the table cell is pressed with different content??

Answer (score 0):

Seems kind of broad, and unclear what you want to do, but if you have a cell (static), then place a textview in the cell, and then whenever that cell is tapped then update the textView

Comment: discard the static, if it possible with dynamic i want to make it when  a cell is pressed the content of the uitext will change

Comment: You can place it in a dynamic cell.  Whatever you do to one cell, all the cells in that table will have. Just make a UITableViewCell subclass and go nuts

Comment: When you use the site, make sure to select answers that help you, as it can help others in the future, and will make people inclined to help you. Otherwise you won't get much help here

Comment: what is the problem what did you mean ?